# Create a checksum for a fetched webpage

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7 and use `requests` to fetch web pages.

I would like to know if the fetched object has changed.

```
r = requests.get(url,headers=None,proxies=None,timeout=int(parms['timeout']))
html = r.text

if checksum(html)!=checksum_last: 
   then do something
else:
    do nothing
```

I will save the checksum in a db.  How do I create a checksum?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the builtin `hashlib` module...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Jon Clements mentions, you can use the [`hashlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) module:

```
>>> import requests
>>> import hashlib
>>> page = requests.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
>>> hashlib.sha256(page.text.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
'807ea5e7c419aefc7a40ba1140ba6ef4001c60f3c21142eb743bc1d393c1bb62'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't need a cryptographic hash function, you can use [Adler-32](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.adler32) or [CRC-32](http://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.crc32) from `zlib`.

```
r = requests.get(url,headers=None,proxies=None,timeout=int(parms['timeout']))
html = r.text
if zlib.adler32(html.encode("utf-8")) != checksum_last:
    print("New page!")
```

Comment: Both of those have [compatibility problems](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.crc32) between versions of Python that can make them inconvenient to use in some situations.

Comment: @agf With the `.encode("utf-8")`, this code seems to work identically in 2.7 and 3.3..

Comment: @agf interesting - do you have a reference handy?

Comment: @JonClements Checkout the [version 2.x docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.crc32): `Changed in version 2.6: The return value is in the range [-2**31, 2**31-1] regardless of platform. In older versions the value would be signed on some platforms and unsigned on others.

Changed in version 3.0: The return value is unsigned and in the range [0, 2**32-1] regardless of platform.`

Comment: @agf They specifically mentioned that they're using Python 2.7, so that shouldn't be a problem. You can find a serious problem in just about any module in Python < 2.6.

Comment: @BrendanLong There is still a compatibility problem between 2.7 and 3.x with the checksums, while sha256 will be compatible everywhere. It's just one less thing to think about.